# Problems with login after startx command

Tags: login-screen

I am running 14.04. after typing `startx` command i cannot login same account again. Login screen is repeatedly showing.

I can login with guest section but i can not login to my another section . 
i just type `startx` and then screen goes blank and after reboot i cannot login  into same account.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Can you still log on to another account?  The guest session?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: @Fabby There's no point even if you can log into guest session. You cannot unmake the changes made by `startx`

Answer (score 2):

I got your question completely. You could try the following method, it solved my problem as well.

- You must have run `startx` with `root` privileges. Doing `sudo startx` or `sudo su; startx` makes the `root` owner of a file called `.Xauthority` required for X session login by `xauth`
- **NEVER** use `sudo` for opening graphical applications. `root` will create files which will be owned by it, which others **can't** access. Since in Ubuntu by default `root` will have no password set, this can severely mess with your settings and your not being able to access your configuration files. Next time **use** a `gksudo` instead.
- Since your `.Xauthority` file is owned by `root`, **there is no way** you can log in.
- Find another terminal, like log in to another account and open terminal, but **don't log in** to  guest account.
- In case you have only one account which you can't log in, then finding a terminal **is difficult** since you can get one only if you can log in.
- In that case find a terminal `tty1` through `tty7` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>through<kbd>F7</kbd>. This should provide you a terminal in case you **have none** at your disposal.
- Enter the login credentials of your troubled account. You can log in through a command line terminal because `.Xauthority` affects **only** X window sessions.
- Do `cd; sudo chown username:groupname .Xauthority;` Replace `username` and `groupname` with your own. **Usually** it is the same.
- If it successfully returns prompt, then do `sudo shutdown -r 0` and login again.

Answer (score 0):

If login screen is repeatly showing even though you enter valid password then follow the following step to fix it.
press **ctrl+alt+f1** to switch to the first console.
then Enter your user name and password.
Then type the command **mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak**
Then type **exit** 
now Press **ctrl+alt+f7** to switch back to Desktop mode.
Now you can login using your user name and password.